# focus to popup input when modal overlay is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this peculiar situation. First, there's a modal and the rest of the page is hidden by overlay:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
.overlay {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 visibility: hidden; //visible when modal pops up of course
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2900;
}
```

Inside modal there are some elements which have the following event listener:

```
el.find('select').on('mousedown', function (e){
    if (event.which === 3) {
    ...popup window containing contenteditable div gets formed and added to modal, it gets el boundingClientRect data to sit tight on it. So far so good, but - 
    popup.focus();
```

does not work. Tried js+jquery and placing popup anywhere on page, but nada. Its not the console question either. Triggering a click on popup has zero results. When I remove overlay all works. Can't figure out the reason...

To reiterate the layers - there's the rest of the page covered by overlay, on that sits a modal (z-index:3000) and popup is called onto it(z-index:3010).

Edit: now here's the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zumbauuo/

Problem persists. Yesterday in original document I was able to get popup focused with this code when removing overlay div and keeping modal structure, today however - not. So I don't know what to think any more.

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but have you tried HTML5 dialog? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog
Its more elegant and updated solution for dialog/modal case.

Comment: @Ciryo: Can u create a fiddle?

Comment: Dialog is definitely elegant but I'm somewhat restricted to use modal in this case. Also, I need Safari support. Thanx for the tip though, I'll definitely squeeze something out of it in the future. As for fiddle - next deadline presses on and cant focus on in right now, sorry. If no ideas thus far, I'll produce a fiddle in the evening.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
.on( "change", handler )
```

Comment: My popup is created on right click on the select field, and its purpose is to provide input where user can add new <option> to it. Not really a conventional way but handy in my situation. Should have explained it more in question,  but as it is, there is no 'change' listener to select needed, in fact the select in itself is irrelevant and popup is the real thing here. Somehow overlay blocks focus() on absolutely positioned element, there's my problem.